# Vanity URL and redirection

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to make a redirection service, which can redirect users to their profile page, based on a vanity url.

The vanity URL will be of the format - www.site.com/username

This will redirect them to a page profile_redirect.php, which will echo the username (The functionality is deeper, but this is all I need help with).

I tried several of the answers posted here, but I am unable to get this to work. At the moment, it does nothing and just gives me a page not found error. I am running this on wamp, and I have localhost's alias set to "proj", so I call "`http://proj/username`", but this gives me page not found.

My current htaccess file (Relevant portion)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L]
```

My current profile_redirect.php file

```
$getName=$_GET["user"];
echo $getName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ profile_redirect.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Fastest response ever, and works perfectly! Thank you! (Its so fast I cant even accept the answer yet :P)

Could you please help me understand what was wrong with my previous rules? If you wouldn't mind :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes definitely I can point what was wrong. Problem was this condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""` which isn't doing anything but comparing `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable with literal `&gt;` and of course this doesn't succeed and your rule doesn't fire.

Comment: Never would have noticed that! Thank you again! :)